# Angular2 Dartlang LOCALE_ID missing

Tags: angular, angular-dart

I'm trying to set the LOCALE_ID in an Angular2 application in Dart so that DateTimes get formatted correctly (Monday->Montag for example). Unfortunately LOCALE_ID isn't at time of writing in angular2/core.dart. Are there plans to add it, or is there another way to set the locale? I've tried setting `<html lang="de">` but this hasn't helped :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what `LOCALE_ID` is supposed to be but for I18N in Dart usually

https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/intl

is used.

Comment: Thanks for the reply :) LOCALE_ID is defined in the typescript version of Angular2, as far as I can see, so that an application-wide locale can be set. ( https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/LOCALE_ID-let.html )

Comment: Angular2 for Dart doesn't have it's own I18N implementation.